# how to return an array of images through web service?

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, web-services

I want to return an array of images from a sql server through a web service written in asp dot net . I could return a single file by sending the byte array back . How to return an array of byte arrays or an image images back to the flex application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it finally by creating an array of byte array on the C# web service,and returning this double dimension array .

Answer (score 1):

You need to load every image/Bytes file on Flex side using **LODER** from its refrence

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.loadBytes(imageByteArray);

and can get notification when image is loaded on event COMPLETE  of

Loader or loader.contentLoaderInfo

i used above method in one of my app but you can also see [Loading Reloaded](http://www.stimuli.com.br/trane/2007/nov/25/loading-reloaded/)

Hopes that helps

Comment: how to return it from server side to flex , using a double dimension byte array ?

Comment: I did it with java Creates a simple Value object With Field on "Java" Side "public byte[] fileContent;" and Mapping this Value object on "Flex" Side is "public var fileContent:ByteArray;" and on Java side i also load byte in "fileContent" using ByteArrayOutputStream because i requried to save/retrive files from Database, you may use similar in .net

Comment: Note ValueObject also have simple  Fields like name, datacreated etc